# SQLite & Sql Alchemy SingletonThreadPool - can I share a connection object?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm getting errors of the form:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 139661426296576 and this is thread id 139662493492992
```

in my multithreaded application.

I'm instantiating my engine with:

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import SingletonThreadPool
db_path = "sqlite:///" + cwd + "/data/data.db"
create_engine(db_path, poolclass=SingletonThreadPool, pool_size=50)
```

I had expected the `SingletonThreadPool` to solve this problem. What am I missing?

(bonus question: for the sake of reduced headache, should I move to MySQL?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using sqlite3 then you just have to pass the `check_same_thread` parameter as below:

```
create_engine(db_path, connect_args={'check_same_thread': False})
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Are there any risky side effects of this? (e.g. inserts being dropped, etc?)

Comment: Actually no, sqlite3 supports multiple threads and handles concurrency. As long as you don't have any specific requirement for your database sqlite is just fine