# Sqlalchemy on multiple write threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-multithreading

The following code works in Python 3.6+, not in Python 3.4.3, not sure at what release it fails. Why is this? I was under the impression that sqlalchemy would handle multiple readers/writers to a file-based db, by hiding it behind a serialiser of the calls, probably. Anyway, this is an indication that I'm not handling this right - how to insert on multiple threads, or one thread off the main thread, in versions < 3.6?

I attempted this at the sqlalchemy `session()` level [sqlalchemy connection pool on multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553415/sqlalchemy-connection-pool-on-multiple-threads)

but was only able to get it to work with an engine, and now I find out only on 3.6.

```
def insert_inventory_table(conn, table, inventory):
    conn.execute(table.insert(), inventory)    

def results_table(conn, table):
    q = select([table])
    data = conn.execute(q).fetchall()
    print('{!r}'.format(data))


def main_0():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://', connect_args={'check_same_thread' : False})
    conn = engine.connect()

    metadata = MetaData(engine)
    table = Table('inventory',
              metadata,
              Column('item_no', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
              Column('desc', String(255), nullable=False),
              Column('volume', Integer, nullable=False)
              )

    metadata.create_all()

    some_inventory = [{'item_no' : 0, 'desc' : 'drone', 'volume' : 12},
                      {'item_no' : 1, 'desc' : 'puddle jumper', 'volume' : 2},
                      {'item_no' : 2, 'desc' : 'pet monkey', 'volume' : 1},
                      {'item_no' : 3, 'desc' : 'bowling ball', 'volume' : 4},
                      {'item_no' : 4, 'desc' : 'electric guitar', 'volume' : 3},
                      {'item_no' : 5, 'desc' : 'bookends', 'volume' : 2}]


    thread_0 = threading.Thread(target=insert_inventory_table, args=(conn, table, some_inventory[0:3]))
    thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=insert_inventory_table, args=(conn, table, some_inventory[3:]))

    thread_0.start()
    thread_1.start()

    return conn, table


if __name__ == '__main__':

    conn,table = main_0()
    results_table(conn, table)
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should not share connection between threads

Comment: sqlalchemy is supposed to account for this use case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469509/sqlite-sql-alchemy-singletonthreadpool-can-i-share-a-connection-object/41469818#41469818

Comment: of course, sqlalchemy has mechanism to work with multi-threads, `scoped_session`, but you didn't use: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#thread-local-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out, you have to use scoped session, so instead of your conn:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
```

And then whenever you connect to your db in a thread, remembeer to open and close a session, you dont want sessions to be shared by threads, because this will lead to bad things, so:

```
def worker(sth):
     session = db_session()
     "do sth very important"
     res = session.query(YourModel).filter(YourModel.sth = sth).first()
     print(res)
     session.close()
```

And then you can use such workers in your multithreaded operations. I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add something to the above answer (as I cannot edit it anymore). With a scoped session you can call other functions, that connect with your db, and you don't have to add your session as an argument to those functions, because every next session created in the same thread will be the same session. So:

```
def worker(sth):
     session = db_session()
     "do sth very important"
     res = session.query(YourModel).filter(YourModel.sth == sth).first()
     your_very_importan_function(sth)

     print(res)
     db_session.remove()

def your_very_important_function(sth):
     session = db_session()    # this session will be the same as the session created in the worker function, and in the worker function, it is different for every thread.
    "do sth even more important"
    res = session.query(YourOtherModel).filter(YourOtherModel.sth == sth).first()
```

In the end, you should remove the session, and not only close it.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html